# Groovy map to json list of objects

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to take a very simple map of objects and produce a list of objects like so. I have this working, but surely there must be a better way with Groovy?

```
private def createConfigJson(Map configMap) {
  def jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder().append("{\n")

  configMap.each { key, value ->
    jsonBuilder.append("  \"$key\": \"$value\",\n")
  }

  // Delete last ',' instead of the newline
  jsonBuilder.deleteCharAt(jsonBuilder.length() - 2)
  jsonBuilder.append("}")
}
```

`createConfigJson([test: 'test', test2: 'test2'])`

will produce:

```
{
  "test": "test",
  "test2": "test2"
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

to serialize map to json object (string)

you can use

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
new JsonBuilder([test: 'test', test2: 'test2']).toPrettyString()
```

or

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonOutput.html

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson([test: 'test', test2: 'test2']))
```